# ¿Como obtener los valores de un `Text` en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy realizando un programa para el almacenamiento de datos de usuario. En un campo `Text` destinado para comentarios necesito obtener los valores allí ingresados para su almacenamiento en BBDD.

Las lineas de interacción con `Entry` obtengo el valor a través del metodo `textvariable=` junto con una variable `nombreIntroducido = StringVar()` sin embargo esta no es compatible con `Text` y no encuentro un método con el cual pueda obtener los valores y lo tengo actualmente así:

```
cuadroID=Entry(frame)
cuadroID.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroID.config(fg="red", justify="right")

cuadroNombre=Entry(frame, textvariable=nombreIntroducido)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroNombre.config(justify="center")

cuadroApellido=Entry(frame, textvariable=apellidoIntroducido)
cuadroApellido.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroApellido.config(justify="center")

cuadroPassword=Entry(frame, textvariable=passwordIntroducido)
cuadroPassword.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroPassword.config(show="*")

cuadroDireccion=Entry(frame, textvariable=direccionIntroducido)
cuadroDireccion.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

cuadroComentarios=Text(frame, width=15, height=5, textariable=comentarioIntroducido)
cuadroComentarios.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10)
scrollVert=Scrollbar(frame, command=cuadroComentarios.yview)
scrollVert.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="nsew")
cuadroComentarios.config(yscrollcommand=scrollVert.set)
```

Comment: Puedes hacerle `cuadroComentarios..get(1.0,tk.END)` para que te guarde todo lo ingresado en el cuadro de texto. Desde la primera linea, hasta el final del cuadro.

Comment: Un detalle, python tiene muchos motores de GUI y TK es solo uno de ellos (En mi opinión: Ni es el mejor, ni el más usado). Así que por favor aclara que estas usando TK cuando hagas preguntas así.

Comment: @gcoronel99 muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba. Ya entendi que los  `Text` son diferente a los `Èntry ` en **Tkinter**